# Ruby on Rails - Show only 3 image pr page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

In my application, I have `Post` & `Slide` models. A `Post` has many `slides`.

Currently, in my `posts#show` view, I show all the slides that belongs to a post.

How can I show only 3 `slides` per page and have a **Next & Prev** button to next *group*?

*Example:* A post has **20 slides**, It only show 3 slide per page with a Next button to the next 3 etc and the URL would for instance be `domain.com/p/posts-title/ps/1`, `domain.com/p/posts-title/ps/2` etc.

This is what I have done now:

1. Created `with_pagination` action in `posts_controller`
2. Added it to my route
3. Created the `with_pagination` view

*in with_pagination view*

```
- @post.slides.order('sort_order ASC').each_slice(4) do |group|
```

*in routes*

```
resources :posts, path: 'p' do
    get 'ps/:page', to: 'posts#with_pagination', as: :xyz
    // i have other stuff here
end
```

*in controller*

```
def with_pagination
    @post = Post.find_by_slug(params[:post_id])
end
```

Now I can show all the slide on that page, but as mentioned I only want to show **3 slides** pr page with a next and prev link to them.

*Ps: I have had almost the same question before but it doesn't work as the same since other one was with use of pagination and pagination is not what I am looking for*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your controller

```
def with_pagination
    @post = Post.find_by_slug(params[:post_id])
    @slides = @post.slides.order('sort_order ASC').page(params[:page]).per(3)
end
```

On the view

```
- @slides.each do |slide|
```

Comment: Thank you so much @arieljoud

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "will_paginate" gem available for the pagination functionality.

Add gem **"will_paginate"** in your gem file and run **bundle install**

In controller write down

*@slides = @post.slides.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3).order('sort_order ASC')*

In view page

```
   *- @slides.each do |slide|
      ......
     end

   = will_paginate @slides*
```

For better understand follow "https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate"